# Why cannot convert from string to int?

Tags: android, string, int

It should be something easy to do, but these commands return error when I try to convert a String to integer:

```
        Intent recibir = getIntent();
        String nombre = recibir.getStringExtra("hora_inicio");

        int numero=0;

        try {
            numero = Integer.parseInt(nombre);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, numero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Android monitor returns this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.cristobal.policlinica, PID: 11025
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.cristobal.policlinica/com.example.cristobal.policlinica.CalendarActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>   0x9
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                       Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource 0x9 
>                                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:286)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.cristobal.policlinica.CalendarActivity.onCreate(CalendarActivity.java:31)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

thanks in advance

Comment: check this `Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID` And set  `Toast.makeText(this, ""+numero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: check if(!nombre.isempty) then convert it to int

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(numero), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Share your code where you are setting intent data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your conversion but with your `Toast.makeText`. When you call `Toast.makeText(this, numero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

It considers `numero` as resId and tries to find the relative string resource in `strings.xml` which fails giving error:

`Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID`

**Instead of**

`Toast.makeText(this, numero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

**DO**

`Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(numero), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: As an opinion, String.valueOf(numero); is more efficient and elegant

Comment: @MarcEstrada yeah, great idea. Updated the answer

Comment: And voted your answer :) there is a lot of lates answer saying same of you, so voted yours

Comment: @MarcEstrada Thanks!

Comment: @Mimmetico great! Remember to mark answer as approved, so that others can benefit too

Comment: @MarcEstrada could you explain how it's more efficient and elegant?

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(numero), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 number = Integer.parseInt(YourStringName.toString());
```